# Prettier conflicts with ?. (question mark and dot) in typescript-react inside of prop-brackets with syntax error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prettier

Expression

```js
<Button
        title={props.children?.toString()}
        buttonStyle={$.buttonStyle}
        titleStyle={$.titleStyle}

      />
```

gives next error

```
SyntaxError: Expression expected.
title={props.children?.toString()}
                      ^
```

Are there any ways to fix it? 
Eslint with prettier-plugin gives the same error.
Problem with parser-typescript.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The propblem is in a new version of Prettier 4.5.0 
If you downgrade your prettier to v4.0.0 - your problem will collapse :)

Answer (score 4):

If your version of Prettier is out of date, it's possible that it doesn't support Optional Chaining which was introduced in [Version 1.19](https://prettier.io/blog/2019/11/09/1.19.0.html). If `prettier` is not saved as a `"devDependency"` in your `package.lock`, then your IDE will default to using any global module for `prettier`. It's recommended to use `prettier` from the project's local dependencies.

To save prettier as a devDependency, run:

```
npm install prettier -D --save-exact
```

Typescript introduced Optional Chaining in October of 2019 with [Version 3.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-7-rc/#optional-chaining) and then Prettier followed up by introducing it in November of 2019 with [Version 1.19](https://prettier.io/blog/2019/11/09/1.19.0.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your `typescript-eslint` plugin.